# What is the correct way to set up a custom header in DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to log correlation id along with all the logs messages.
I used a DelegatingHandler to add correlation id to the request and response headers for which I came across two approaches:

**First:**

```
// In the DelagatingHandler
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
    request.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-Id", correlationId);
    ...
}
```

In order to get this header in the logger class, I had to do the following *(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers did not contain this header)*:

```
var requestMessage = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
var corId = requestMessage.Headers.GetValues("X-Correlation-Id");
```

**Second:**

```
// In the DelegatingHandler
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-Id", correlationId);

// In the logger class
var correlationId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("X-Correlation-Id");
```

Which one is the correct approach?
Why HttpContext.Current.Request does not contain this header for the first approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would say your first approach, which is `request.Headers.Add`. It's easy to unit test. Honestly any pre-request data go with HttpRequestMessage.

To answer your second question there is a good reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821090/5977042)